# How to add a transition to all pages in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

By default jQuery Mobile transitions is set to "fade". I know i can add a transition to all links, but since I'm using the same transition "slide" for all pages is there a way that i don't have to `data-transition="slide"` to all links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this on your head tag:

```
<script>    
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';    
</script>
```